# Unqualified name lookup does not look in local namespace after using declaration

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup, using-directives

```
namespace A
{
    int overloaded_f(float some_float);
    enum class Enum { Value };
}

namespace B
{
    int overloaded_f(A::Enum some_enum);
    int f(A::Enum some_enum){
        using A::overloaded_f;
        // using B::overloaded_f;

        // return B::overloaded_f(some_enum) + overloaded_f(0.0f);
        return overloaded_f(some_enum) + overloaded_f(0.0f);

        /* error: cannot convert 'A::Enum' to 'float'
           14 |         return overloaded_f(some_enum) + overloaded_f(0.0f);
              |                             ^~~~~~~~~
              |                             |
              |                             A::Enum
        */
    }
}

int main(){ 
    A::Enum a = A::Enum::Value;
    return B::f(a);
}
```

[Link to Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/chKPdjG81).

Uncommenting the (`//`) code lines would remove the error.

From [basic.lookup.unqual](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.unqual#:%7E:text=In,enclosing%20namespace):

> §6.4.1 Unqualified name lookup [basic.lookup.unqual]
>
> 1. In all the cases listed in [basic.lookup.unqual], the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories;
>    name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name. If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.
> 2. The declarations from the namespace nominated by a using-directive become visible in a namespace enclosing the using-directive; see
>    [namespace.udir]. For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules
>    described in [basic.lookup.unqual], the declarations from the
>    namespace nominated by the using-directive are considered members of
>    that enclosing namespace.

Does the code snippet fail to compile because `name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the code snippet fail to compile because name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name?

You're correct. The lookup of `overloaded_f` in the expression `overloaded_f(some_enum)` has two components:

- The unqualified component: this stops searching outward as soon as it finds a declaration, which in this case means it stops at `using A::overloaded_f`.
- The argument-dependent component: this only looks inside the namespace associated with its argument type. In this case, the associated namespace is `A` (the namespace in which the enum type is declared). It does not find anything that is inside namespace `B`.